# i am using i18n for my project i did converted the string which is fine for the normal tag but not for nested tag

Tags: html, next.js

i want to convert div elements to different language without using multiple variable

sample:

Trusted by Over 2.5 Million Students Globally 
{t('index_Make_trusted')} {t('index_Make_million')} {t('index_Make_globally')}

this is working fine but i want to use one variable.

like this

{t('trustedBy')}
{t('trustedBy')}

.json file

"trustedBy": "Trusted by Over 2.5 Million Students Globally",

output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxfxx.png)